# Creating view in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17 returns error (but the query itself works)

Tags: sql-server, view, concatenation

I am trying to create my first View in The Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17. I just basically followed few steps described in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-views?view=sql-server-ver15

Then I pasted earlier prepared select statement which works fine and without any error. But used for view creator returns an error:
"The CONCAT function requires 2 argument(s),
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'"

I wonder if there is any function which I can use while executing the query but I should not use while creating a view. Or maybe the syntax for this purpose should be different?

Since the error message mentioned the concat() function, here is an example of use concat() in my select statement:

```
concat('r-',year(getdate())-YEAR(A.DATA))
cast(concat(substring(C.KOD_SEZONU,3,4)+1,'-03-31') as date)
```

[error pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRwB9.png)

The original select statement:

```sql
SELECT
C.KOD_SEZONU,
substring(C.KOD_SEZONU,1,2) SEZON,
CASE 
WHEN C.KOD_SEZONU ='PERMAN'                                                                                         THEN 'REGULAR'
WHEN SUBSTRING(C.KOD_SEZONU,1,2)='JZ' AND A.DATA <= cast(concat(substring(C.KOD_SEZONU,3,4)+1,'-03-31') as date)    THEN 'REGULAR'
WHEN SUBSTRING(C.KOD_SEZONU,1,2)='WL' AND A.DATA <= cast(concat(substring(C.KOD_SEZONU,3,4),'-09-30') as date)      THEN 'REGULAR'
ELSE 'OUTLET' END KOLEKCJA,

YEAR(A.DATA) ROK,
MONTH(A.DATA) MC,
DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,A.DATA) TYD,

cast(concat(YEAR(A.DATA),'_',RIGHT('00'+CAST(MONTH(A.DATA) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)) as varchar(7)) ROK_MC,
cast(CONCAT(
(CASE 
WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,A.DATA)>50 AND MONTH(A.DATA)=1 THEN YEAR(A.DATA)-1
WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,A.DATA)=1 AND MONTH(A.DATA)=12 THEN YEAR(A.DATA)+1
ELSE YEAR(A.DATA) END)
,'_',RIGHT('00'+CAST(DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,A.DATA) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)) as varchar(7)) ROK_TYD,

CASE 
when MONTH(A.DATA) <4 and month(getdate())<4 then concat('r-',year(getdate())-YEAR(A.DATA))
when MONTH(A.DATA) <4 and month(getdate())>=4 then concat('r-',year(getdate())+1-YEAR(A.DATA))
when MONTH(A.DATA) >=4 and month(getdate())<4 then concat('r-',year(getdate())-1-YEAR(A.DATA))
when MONTH(A.DATA) >=4 and month(getdate())>=4 then concat('r-',year(getdate())+1-1-YEAR(A.DATA))
else 'x' end ROK_B,

A.LOKALIZACJA,
e.SHOP_REGION,
E.POSTAL_CODE,
E.TYP_SKLEPU,
E.KATEGORIA_SKLEPU_LATO KATEGORIA_SKLEPU,

CASE WHEN C.NR_REFERENCJI IN('5CD687','5CD999','5CD855','5ED950','5ED951','5ED952')     THEN 'PUDEŁKA'
WHEN C.NR_REFERENCJI IN('REKLAM')                                                       THEN 'REKLAMÓWKI'
WHEN C.MODEL LIKE'TORBA PAPIER%'                                                        THEN 'TORBY PAP.'
WHEN C.NR_REFERENCJI IN('56O637') OR C.MODEL LIKE'BON%'                                 THEN 'BONY' 
WHEN C.NR_REFERENCJI LIKE '2 GAT%' OR C.MODEL LIKE '2 GAT%'                             THEN '2 GATUNEK'
WHEN SUBSTRING(A.ID_POZYCJI_MAG,1,1) IN('D','M')                                        THEN SUBSTRING(A.ID_POZYCJI_MAG,1,1)
WHEN REPLACE(C.NR_REFERENCJI,' ','')='' OR C.NR_REFERENCJI IS NULL                      THEN 'INNE'
ELSE SUBSTRING(C.NR_REFERENCJI,1,1) END ASO,
C.MODEL,
substring(a.ID_POZYCJI_MAG,1,9) as REFCO,
C.NR_REFERENCJI,
D.KOLOR_KOD,
c.WZOR_KOD_DOSTAWCY,
link.produkt_link link,
D.ROZMIAR,
C.KOD_LINII,
C.DOSTAWCA,
C.KRAJ_POCHODZENIA,

cast(CONCAT(YEAR(MIN(CASE WHEN E.KATEGORIA_SKLEPU_LATO IN('A','B','C') AND A.LOKALIZACJA NOT IN('S269','S777') AND A.KONTRAHENT IN('S5','S6') AND A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('MM+  ') THEN A.DATA ELSE NULL END)),'_',RIGHT('00'+CAST(MONTH(MIN(CASE WHEN E.KATEGORIA_SKLEPU_LATO IN('A','B','C') AND A.LOKALIZACJA NOT IN('S269','S777') AND A.KONTRAHENT IN('S5','S6') AND A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('MM+  ') THEN A.DATA ELSE NULL END)) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)) as varchar(7))          WEJSCIE_ROK_MC,
cast(CONCAT(YEAR(MIN(CASE WHEN E.KATEGORIA_SKLEPU_LATO IN('A','B','C') AND A.LOKALIZACJA NOT IN('S269','S777') AND A.KONTRAHENT IN('S5','S6') AND A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('MM+  ') THEN A.DATA ELSE NULL END)),'_',RIGHT('00'+CAST(DATEPART(WEEK,MIN(CASE WHEN E.KATEGORIA_SKLEPU_LATO IN('A','B','C') AND A.LOKALIZACJA NOT IN('S269','S777') AND A.KONTRAHENT IN('S5','S6') AND A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('MM+  ') THEN A.DATA ELSE NULL END)) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)) as varchar(7))  WEJSCIE_ROK_TYD,
CAST(MIN(CASE WHEN E.KATEGORIA_SKLEPU_LATO IN('A','B','C') AND A.LOKALIZACJA NOT IN('S269','S777') AND A.KONTRAHENT IN('S5','S6') AND A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('MM+  ') THEN A.DATA ELSE NULL END) AS DATE) WEJSCIE_SKLEP_DATA,
CAST(MIN(CASE WHEN A.LOKALIZACJA IN('FOT') AND A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('MM+  ') THEN A.DATA ELSE NULL END) AS DATE) WEJSCIE_FOT_DATA,

CENNIK.CENA_I CENA_I_BRUTTO,
CENNIK.CENA_AKT CENA_AKT_BRUTTO,
max(A.KOSZT_MAGAZYNOWY) KJ,

CASE 
WHEN A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('KMS  ','KMK  ','PZ   ','PZI  ','PZISC','ZPZ  ','PZC  ','WSC  ','PW   ','KMK  ','KMS  ','PKU  ')    THEN 'DOSTAWA_ZEW'
WHEN A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('MM+  ','KM-  ','KM+  ')                                                                            THEN 'DOSTAWA_WEW'
WHEN A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('WZ   ','ZW   ','WZT  ','BONSP')                                                                    THEN 'SPRZEDAŻ_SPRZEDAŻ'
WHEN A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('ZW   ')                                                                                            THEN 'SPRZEDAŻ_ZWROT'
WHEN A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('INW  ','INW+ ','PL   ')                                                                            THEN 'INWENTARYZACJA'
WHEN A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('RWW  ')                                                                                            THEN 'ZUŻYCIE_WEW'
WHEN A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('MM-  ','KMM- ')                                                                                    THEN 'WYCOFANIE_WEW'
ELSE 'NN' END TYP_TRANSAKCJI,

CASE
WHEN E.KATEGORIA_SKLEPU_LATO IN('A','B','C') AND A.LOKALIZACJA NOT IN('S269','S777')            THEN 'SKLEPY_REGULARNE'
WHEN E.KATEGORIA_SKLEPU_LATO IN('O') AND A.LOKALIZACJA NOT IN('S269','S777')                    THEN 'SKLEPY_OUTLETOWE'
WHEN E.KATEGORIA_SKLEPU_LATO IN('E') AND A.LOKALIZACJA NOT IN('S269','S777')                    THEN 'SKLEPY INTERNETOWE'
WHEN A.LOKALIZACJA IN('S5','S6')                                                                THEN 'MAGAZYNY'
WHEN (E.KATEGORIA_SKLEPU_LATO NOT IN('A','B','C','O','E') OR A.LOKALIZACJA IN('S269','S777'))   THEN 'POZOSTAŁE'
ELSE 'NN' END LOKALIZACJA_GRUPA,

SUM(A.ILOSC*(CASE WHEN A.KIERUNEK_TRANSAKCJI='-' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END)            )   TRANSAKCJA_ILOŚĆ,
SUM(A.ILOSC*(CASE WHEN A.KIERUNEK_TRANSAKCJI='-' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END)*CENNIK.CENA_I/1.23 )   TRANSAKCJA_WART_NETTO_I_CENA,
SUM(A.ILOSC*(CASE WHEN A.KIERUNEK_TRANSAKCJI='-' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END)*A.T_KWOTA_NETTO    )   TRANSAKCJA_WART_NETTO,
SUM(A.ILOSC*(CASE WHEN A.KIERUNEK_TRANSAKCJI='-' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END)*KOSZT.KOSZT_MAX    )   TRANSAKCJA_KOSZT

FROM PBH_BI.DBO.RAPTOR_TRANSAKCJE_MAGAZYNOWE_TAB A
LEFT JOIN PBH_BI.DBO.RAPTOR_POZYCJE_MAGAZYNOWE_TAB D ON A.FIRMA = D.FIRMA AND A.ID_POZYCJI_MAG = D.ID_POZYCJI_MAG
LEFT JOIN PBH_BI.DBO.RAPTOR_REFERENCJE_TAB C ON D.FIRMA = C.FIRMA AND C.ID_REFERENCJI = D.ID_REFERENCJI
LEFT JOIN PBH_BI.DBO.T_RAPTOR_SKLEPIKI_INFO_TAB E ON A.LOKALIZACJA = E.SHOP
LEFT JOIN PBH_BI.DBO.T_RAPTOR_SKLEPIKI_INFO_TAB E2 ON A.KONTRAHENT = E2.SHOP
INNER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT
X.NR_REFERENCJI,
X.KOLOR,
X.KOD_SEZONU,
AKT.CENA CENA_AKT,
I.CENA CENA_I
FROM
(select DISTINCT
CPT.NR_REFERENCJI,
CPT.KOLOR,
REF.KOD_SEZONU,
MIN(CPT.PRIORYTET_CENNIK) AKT_PRIORYTET_CENNIK,
MAX(CASE WHEN CT.TYP_CENNIKA = 'GLOWNY' THEN CPT.ID_CENNIKA ELSE '0' END) I_PRIORYTET_CENNIK
from PBH_BI.DBO.RAPTOR_ZK_CENNIK_POZYCJE_TAB CPT
left JOIN PBH_BI.DBO.RAPTOR_POZYCJE_MAGAZYNOWE_TAB REF  ON REF.NR_REFERENCJI    = CPT.NR_REFERENCJI AND REF.KOLOR_KOD   = CPT.KOLOR
left JOIN PBH_BI.dbo.RAPTOR_ZK_CENNIK_TAB CT            ON CT.ID_DOKUMENTU      = CPT.ID_CENNIKA    AND CT.FIRMA        = CPT.FIRMA AND CT.KOD_SEZONU           = REF.KOD_SEZONU 
--WHERE CPT.WAZNY_OD <'20200101'
GROUP BY CPT.ID_REFERENCJI, CPT.NR_REFERENCJI, CPT.KOLOR, REF.KOD_SEZONU) X
LEFT JOIN PBH_BI.DBO.RAPTOR_ZK_CENNIK_POZYCJE_TAB AKT   ON X.NR_REFERENCJI      = AKT.NR_REFERENCJI AND X.KOLOR         = AKT.KOLOR AND X.AKT_PRIORYTET_CENNIK  = AKT.PRIORYTET_CENNIK
LEFT JOIN PBH_BI.dbo.RAPTOR_ZK_CENNIK_TAB AKT2          ON AKT2.ID_DOKUMENTU    = AKT.ID_CENNIKA    AND AKT2.FIRMA      = AKT.FIRMA AND AKT2.KOD_SEZONU         = X.KOD_SEZONU
LEFT JOIN PBH_BI.DBO.RAPTOR_ZK_CENNIK_POZYCJE_TAB I     ON X.NR_REFERENCJI      = I.NR_REFERENCJI   AND X.KOLOR         = I.KOLOR   AND X.I_PRIORYTET_CENNIK    = I.ID_CENNIKA
LEFT JOIN PBH_BI.dbo.RAPTOR_ZK_CENNIK_TAB I2            ON I2.ID_DOKUMENTU      = I.ID_CENNIKA      AND I2.FIRMA        = I.FIRMA   AND I2.KOD_SEZONU           = X.KOD_SEZONU
) CENNIK
ON CENNIK.NR_REFERENCJI = C.NR_REFERENCJI AND CENNIK.KOLOR = D.KOLOR_KOD AND CENNIK.KOD_SEZONU = C.KOD_SEZONU
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT
SUBSTRING(ID_POZYCJI_MAG,1,6) REFERENCJA,
SUBSTRING(ID_POZYCJI_MAG,7,3) KOLOR,
MAX(KOSZT_MAGAZYNOWY) KOSZT_MAX
FROM PBH_BI.DBO.RAPTOR_TRANSAKCJE_MAGAZYNOWE_TAB A
GROUP BY 
SUBSTRING(ID_POZYCJI_MAG,1,6),
SUBSTRING(ID_POZYCJI_MAG,7,3)) KOSZT ON KOSZT.REFERENCJA=C.NR_REFERENCJI AND D.KOLOR_KOD = KOSZT.KOLOR

left join
(select distinct
  substring(sku,1,9) refco,
  produkt_link
  from
  pbh_bi.dbo.dim_magento_product) link on link.refco = substring(a.ID_POZYCJI_MAG,1,9)
WHERE 

C.KOD_SEZONU IN('JZ2016','JZ2017','JZ2018','JZ2019','JZ2020','JZ2021','WL2016','WL2017','WL2018','WL2019','WL2020','WL2021','PERMAN')
--AND A.DATA ='20200810'
--AND substring(a.ID_POZYCJI_MAG,1,9) ='4JL004831'

GROUP BY
C.KOD_SEZONU,
CASE 
WHEN C.KOD_SEZONU ='PERMAN'                                                                                         THEN 'REGULAR'
WHEN SUBSTRING(C.KOD_SEZONU,1,2)='JZ' AND A.DATA <= cast(concat(substring(C.KOD_SEZONU,3,4)+1,'-03-31') as date)    THEN 'REGULAR'
WHEN SUBSTRING(C.KOD_SEZONU,1,2)='WL' AND A.DATA <= cast(concat(substring(C.KOD_SEZONU,3,4),'-09-30') as date)      THEN 'REGULAR'
ELSE 'OUTLET' END,

YEAR(A.DATA),
MONTH(A.DATA),
DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,A.DATA),

cast(concat(YEAR(A.DATA),'_',RIGHT('00'+CAST(MONTH(A.DATA) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)) as varchar(7)),
cast(CONCAT(
(CASE 
WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,A.DATA)>50 AND MONTH(A.DATA)=1 THEN YEAR(A.DATA)-1
WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,A.DATA)=1 AND MONTH(A.DATA)=12 THEN YEAR(A.DATA)+1
ELSE YEAR(A.DATA) END)
,'_',RIGHT('00'+CAST(DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,A.DATA) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)) as varchar(7)),

CASE 
when MONTH(A.DATA) <4 and month(getdate())<4 then concat('r-',year(getdate())-YEAR(A.DATA))
when MONTH(A.DATA) <4 and month(getdate())>=4 then concat('r-',year(getdate())+1-YEAR(A.DATA))
when MONTH(A.DATA) >=4 and month(getdate())<4 then concat('r-',year(getdate())-1-YEAR(A.DATA))
when MONTH(A.DATA) >=4 and month(getdate())>=4 then concat('r-',year(getdate())+1-1-YEAR(A.DATA))
else 'x' end,

A.LOKALIZACJA,
e.SHOP_REGION,
E.POSTAL_CODE,
E.TYP_SKLEPU,
E.KATEGORIA_SKLEPU_LATO,

CASE WHEN C.NR_REFERENCJI IN('5CD687','5CD999','5CD855','5ED950','5ED951','5ED952') THEN 'PUDEŁKA'
WHEN C.NR_REFERENCJI IN('REKLAM')                                                   THEN 'REKLAMÓWKI'
WHEN C.MODEL LIKE'TORBA PAPIER%'                                                    THEN 'TORBY PAP.'
WHEN C.NR_REFERENCJI IN('56O637') OR C.MODEL LIKE'BON%'                             THEN 'BONY' 
WHEN C.NR_REFERENCJI LIKE '2 GAT%' OR C.MODEL LIKE '2 GAT%'                         THEN '2 GATUNEK'
WHEN SUBSTRING(A.ID_POZYCJI_MAG,1,1) IN('D','M')                                    THEN SUBSTRING(A.ID_POZYCJI_MAG,1,1)
WHEN REPLACE(C.NR_REFERENCJI,' ','')='' OR C.NR_REFERENCJI IS NULL                  THEN 'INNE'
ELSE SUBSTRING(C.NR_REFERENCJI,1,1) END,
C.MODEL,
substring(a.ID_POZYCJI_MAG,1,9),
C.NR_REFERENCJI,
D.KOLOR_KOD,
c.WZOR_KOD_DOSTAWCY,
link.produkt_link,
D.ROZMIAR,
C.KOD_LINII,
C.DOSTAWCA,
C.KRAJ_POCHODZENIA,

CENNIK.CENA_I,
CENNIK.CENA_AKT,

CASE 
WHEN A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('KMS  ','KMK  ','PZ   ','PZI  ','PZISC','ZPZ  ','PZC  ','WSC  ','PW   ','KMK  ','KMS  ','PKU  ')    THEN 'DOSTAWA_ZEW'
WHEN A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('MM+  ','KM-  ','KM+  ')                                                                            THEN 'DOSTAWA_WEW'
WHEN A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('WZ   ','ZW   ','WZT  ','BONSP')                                                                    THEN 'SPRZEDAŻ_SPRZEDAŻ'
WHEN A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('ZW   ')                                                                                            THEN 'SPRZEDAŻ_ZWROT'
WHEN A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('INW  ','INW+ ','PL   ')                                                                            THEN 'INWENTARYZACJA'
WHEN A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('RWW  ')                                                                                            THEN 'ZUŻYCIE_WEW'
WHEN A.TYP_DOKUMENTU_MAG IN('MM-  ','KMM- ')                                                                                    THEN 'WYCOFANIE_WEW'
ELSE 'NN' END,

CASE
WHEN E.KATEGORIA_SKLEPU_LATO IN('A','B','C') AND A.LOKALIZACJA NOT IN('S269','S777')            THEN 'SKLEPY_REGULARNE'
WHEN E.KATEGORIA_SKLEPU_LATO IN('O') AND A.LOKALIZACJA NOT IN('S269','S777')                    THEN 'SKLEPY_OUTLETOWE'
WHEN E.KATEGORIA_SKLEPU_LATO IN('E') AND A.LOKALIZACJA NOT IN('S269','S777')                    THEN 'SKLEPY INTERNETOWE'
WHEN A.LOKALIZACJA IN('S5','S6')                                                                THEN 'MAGAZYNY'
WHEN (E.KATEGORIA_SKLEPU_LATO NOT IN('A','B','C','O','E') OR A.LOKALIZACJA IN('S269','S777'))   THEN 'POZOSTAŁE'
ELSE 'NN' END
```

Comment: Please provide your `create view` attempt in full. An extract from your attempt does not provide enough information here. See [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `CONCAT`'s behaviour doesn't change if you're using it in a `VIEW` or outside of one.

Comment: I added the whole select statement.